# How to batch process converting all .sav to flat file that are in a folder in R ?

Tags: r, spss

Below is my code to convert .sav to a flat file format that works well, my issue raises when I have more than 50 files. Any suggestions on how I can process all the files available in a folder in a loop ?

```
  #load library foreign to read spss 
  library(foreign) 

  #set working directory first 
  setwd("M:\\Files\\Linear Reg") 

  #read .sav file 
  data <-read.spss('Computed_Copy.sav', to.data.frame=TRUE,use.value.labels=FALSE) 
  write.csv(data, "Computed_Copy.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First list all files in your folder with ending .sav

```
files <- list.files(path = 'your/path/tofolder', pattern = '.sav')
for(f in files){ # iterate over them 
  data <-read.spss(f, to.data.frame=TRUE,use.value.labels=FALSE) 
  write.csv(data, paste0(strsplit(f, split = '.', fixed =  T)[[1]][1], '.csv')) 
# the stringsplit removes the wrong ending and the paste adds .csv
}
```

Comment: Yes that explains it well, will share the results once I try implementing it in my code