# Use looping variable for .gz files with fread

Tags: r, fread

I am trying to use fread to loop through a direcotry of .gz files
fread works great for a single file here:

```
d <- fread("gunzip -c file.gz")
```

However if there a way to use fileName as loop variable here? this does not seem to work.

```
fn<- list.files(path="/...)
for (fileName in fn){
  df <- fread("gunzip -c fileName")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to batch process converting all .sav to flat file that are in a folder in R ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693759/how-to-batch-process-converting-all-sav-to-flat-file-that-are-in-a-folder-in-r)

Comment: What's the error msg? It looks like there is a missing ".

Comment: `fread(paste("gunzip -c", fileName)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate `fileName` which is a variable to the command.  E.g.:

```
fn<- list.files(path="/...)
for (fileName in fn){
  df <- fread(paste0("gunzip -c ", fn))
}
```